# Reduce recipe echoing in make

Tags: makefile

I know the silent flag (-s) for make will hide the recipe echoing completely, however this makes it hard to see progress.

For example currently I have hundreds of lines such as (I've broken up the line to fit SO):

```
g++  -I.     -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-literal-suffix
-Wno-unused-but-set-variable `wx-config --cxxflags --unicode=no`
-MT dialog_export.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/dialog_export.Tpo
-c -o dialog_export.o dialog_export.cpp
```

It would be great if it could just print part of the line, say without the flags, something like:

```
g++ dialog_export.o dialog_export.cpp
```

Or just some way of seeing progress, but without spamming the console with a tonne of messages.

Comment: I don't think there is an make functionality to do so. It can be trivial to modify makefile if it uses pattern rules, though. Another way may be writing wrapper (e.g. in bash) and using it as substitute for `CXX`, which will parse command string, echo interesting options, and execute g++ (ugly; highly not-recommended).

Answer (score 1):

I like rules like this:

```
dialog_export.o: dialog_export.cpp
    @echo $@...
    @g++ -I. -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-literal-suffix -Wno-unused-but-set-variable `wx-config --cxxflags --unicode=no` -MT dialog_export.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/dialog_export.Tpo -c -o $@ $<
```

The leading '@' symbols suppress command echoing, and the first command echoes the name of the target:

```
dialog_export.o...
```

If you have a makefile with hundreds of rules, you can convert them all to that form in minutes with a good editor. Or faster with a macro or sed, if you're bold.

(If you have hundreds of lines like that, your makefile can probably be simplified quite a lot, but that's for another day.)

Answer (score 0):

A number of build systems from the autotools to the kernel build system to CMake, etc. do this sort of thing.

The trick is to dynamically control whether the silencing `@` is present on the recipe lines or not and if it is to replace it with a *manual* echo of some friendlier message.

To get a message like what you want you would use something like this:

```
E_g++ := @echo 'g++ $(filter %.o,$^) $@'

%.o: %.cpp
    $(E_g++)g++ ... -o $@ $^
```

To make this sort of thing easier for myself in projects that don't use the autotools or anything like that I wrote [Silent Make Rules](https://github.com/deryni/silent-make-rules).

Which you would use like this:

```
include silent_rules.mk

$(eval $(call vrule,G++,g++ $$(filter %.o,$$^) $$@))

%.o: %.cpp:
        $(SR_V_G++)g++ ... -o $@ $^
```

This would also (like the autotools and kernel make versions) allow you to specify `V=1` on the make command line to go back to the normal make output and use `V=-1` to silence the output entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `$(Q)`:

```
ifeq ("$(V)","1")
Q :=
vecho = @echo
else
Q := @
vecho = @true
endif

somerule:
    $(vecho) building $@ verbosely
    $(Q)do command
```

You can then modify your pattern rules to only output the text you care about.  If you need more verbose, then you just build with `make V=1`.   I don't think there's any shortcut in make to doing this automatically save piping your output through `sed` (which I wouldn't recommend).